# Trying to upload video from a web app to Google Drive but getting zero bytes due to incorrect binary data

Tags: javascript, filereader, arraybuffer, google-drive-shared-drive, typed-arrays

The purpose of the code is to upload files to Google Drive from a web app programmatically using JavaScript. The part that uploads documents is working okay, but the video part is still not working. I still need help with getting the binary data from the array buffer. I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to improve my code and finally get it to work. Thanks!

Function attached to a button with an event listener

```
async function uploadVideoFile(){

  let input = document.getElementById('upload-video');
  let file = input.files[0];
  let res = await getFiles(file).catch(err => alert(err.message)); 

  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(response => {
    //console.log(response)
  })
  .withFailureHandler(response => {
    //console.log(response)
  })
  .uploadToGoogleDrive(res);

} //CLOSES FUNCTION
```

Function for getting files

```
function getFiles(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let data;
    let obj = {};
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      if(!file) return;
      if(file.type.includes('video')){

        let chars  = new Uint8Array(file);
        let CHUNK_SIZE = 0x8000; 
        let index = 0;
        let length = chars.length;
        let result = '';
        let slice;
        while (index < length) {
          slice = chars.subarray(index, Math.min(index + CHUNK_SIZE, length)); 
          result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, slice);
          index += CHUNK_SIZE;
        }

        data = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
        let str = binArrayToString(data.buffer)
        obj = { binary: str, mimeType: file.type, fileName: file.name };
      }else{ //If not video
        data = e.target.result.split(",");
        obj = { binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], fileName: file.name };
      }
      resolve(obj);
    }
    if (file) {
      if(file.type.includes('video')){
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }else{
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    } else {
      reject("No file");
    }
  });
} //CLOSES FUNCTION
```

Code for converting array buffer to string

```
let binArrayToString = function(binArray) {
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < binArray.length; i++) {        
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(binArray[i]));
  }
  return str;
} //CLOSES FUNCTION
```

Server-side function for uploading to Google Drive

```
function uploadToGoogleDrive(obj){

  const FOLDER_ID = '';
  let blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.binary), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID); 
  folder.createFile(blob).getId();

} //CLOSES FUNCTION
```

Comment: `file` is already a blob (`File` objects are a subset of `Blob`) shouldn't need all the work of reading the contents putting it into an arraybuffer just to put back into a blob

Comment: Response appreciated, but it doesn't fix why I'm not getting any binary data/bytes for my video upload.